# How to install the play store applications not available in my country

Tags: google-play-store, installation, vpn

I am a student reviewing multiple COVID tracing applications deployed in various countries around the world. Although I'm located in the US, I'm also interested in applications that other countries have deployed.

As far as I understand, to do that I would need to find a VPN server in the country I am interested in and browse Play Store from there. It looks that people all around the internet advise to:

1. Connect to the VPN,
2. Remove cache and data from Play Store, and
3. Restart Play store.

However, this does not work for me. Play Store still lists only the applications available in the US and prices in US dollars.

I have checked whether my VPN works and it does. whatismyipaddress.com shows that at least my search queries coming from the browser go through a foreign VPN server.

Comment: I don't have any advice right now other than this is going to be particularly challenging because Google Play services is really intelligent when it comes to detecting what country you are in.  In other words, a VPN is not likely to give you any advantage.

Comment: In addition to the VPN, you also need a working payment method for that country. Otherwise, try alternative markets instead.

Comment: When downloading of APKs form Google the "location" is not determined by your IP address. Therefore using a VPN is useless. The PlayStore does send the country information in every request.